# Почему оператор = должен быть нестатическим именно членом класса?

Tags: c++, операторы

Я правильно понимаю, что это нужно для того, чтобы никак не было возможности передать левый операнд как rvalue? И почему он еще должен быть именно нестатическим?

Comment: А как вы себе представляете статический член? Правильно, он для всех объектов.  Оператор изменяет объект, значит будут изменены все ообъекты, если его сделать статическим, И причем тут левый операнд? Пример приводите.

Comment: [Левый операнд может быть rvalue](https://godbolt.org/z/87T7dP6W8). А членом класса он должен быть сугубо по историческим причинам.

Comment: @user7860670, сугубо исторические причины тоже имеют свои причины...

Answer (score 1):

Конструкторы и операторы присваивания генерируются компилятором, при отсутствии их пользовательских определений. Если вы напишете `оператор =` как не член класса, то он все равно не будет вызван, потому что генерированным компилятором оператор имеет приоритет, и тем более будет нарушено правило одного определения.Поэтому `оператор=` должен быть членом класса. Он не может быть статическим, поскольку имеет доступ к указателью this, который не статический, а именно, изменяется только целевой объект а не все объекты изменяются при изменении одного.

Comment: Правило одного определения нарушено не будет (можете проверить на каком-нибудь другом операторе). Остальная часть ответа похожа на правду.